# Multiple filters on SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, max

I have been reading many topics about filtering SQL queries, but none seems to apply to my case, so I'm in need of a bit of help. I have the following data on a SQL table.

```
Date                    item     quantity moved   quantity in stock sequence

13-03-2012 16:51:00    xpto         2                      2           1 
13-03-2012 16:51:00    xpto        -2                      0           2
21-03-2012 15:31:21    zyx          4                      6           1
21-03-2012 16:20:11    zyx          6                      12          2
22-03-2012 12:51:12    zyx         -3                      9           1
```

So this is quantities moved in the warehouse, and the problem is on the first two rows which was a reception and return at the same time, because I'm trying to make a query which gives me the stock at a given time of all items. I use `max(date)` but i don't get the right quantity on result.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you want `SUM("quantity moved")` to get the total quantity you had at that time?

Comment: This is a pretty bad design. If you could change the schema, I would recommend that you track movement of each item and you can then query how many have moved and how many you have in stock.

Comment: well, its a bit more complex, and i can't use sum, because the program has a another way of controlling the quantitys signal, it can be positive, and still decrease the quantity.

Comment: SQL-Server, which version? 2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  item, qty_in_stock
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY item_date DESC, sequence DESC) rn
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   item_date <= @date_of_stock
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: WHERE   item_date <= @date_of_stock, i didn't understand this part, there is only a date, and thats the date of when the item was moved in or out.

Comment: @Dinarte: "make a query which gives me the stock at a given time of all items". `@date_of_stock` is the parameter, the "given time".

Comment: +1 . . . This is the right answer.  I didn't notice the quantity in stock field when I answered.

Comment: You are a genius, it worked!!! Really, thank you so much!! I must now study this query, to understand how it works, im not familiar with some terms.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on SQL-Server 2012, these are several nice features added.

You can use the **[`LAST_VALUE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234.aspx)** - or the `FIRST_VALUE()` - function, in combination with a `ROWS` or `RANGE` window frame (see **[`OVER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)** clause):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   item,
   LAST_VALUE(quantity_in_stock) OVER (PARTITION BY item 
                                       ORDER BY date, sequence
                                       ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                                                AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
           AS quantity_in_stock
FROM  tableX
WHERE date <= @date_of_stock
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `where` clause and do the summation:

```
select item, sum([quantity moved])
from t
group by item
where t.date <= @DESIREDDATETIME
```

If you put a date in for the desired datetime, remember that goes to midnight when the day starts.